# Have a button open the right form JQuery

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, forms

I have a while loop in my php page which sets a different id for every button and form through a counter variable. Every button has to open a different form (they each have different default information preselected, this is for a prescription renewal ability). I can get this to work by having in my javascript a click function for every id which calls a show on the right form. But, obviously this is not scalable, and so it cannot adapt to the amount of prescriptions I have. Looking through the web, I saw people using classes and the id starts with solutions to this problem. However, when I use this solution, the buttons open all the forms... not the desired behavior. Currently my javascript function is the following:

```
$('[id^="add-renew-link"]').click(function () {
    $('[id^="add-renew-form"]').show();
});
```

Like mentioned above, the function does get called by all different IDs button. That code however opens all the forms every time one of the buttons get click. IDs are actually of the form add-renew-form0, add-renew-form1, add-renew-form2... (same pattern for add-renew-link). Forms and links with the same number at the end are meant to be linked. Does anybody know how I can achieve this? Thanks a lot!!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're close.  The `$('[id^="add-renew-form"]').show();` is going to match ALL ELEMENTS that start w/ "add-renew-form" as the id, so that's why you're experiencing all forms being shown when clicking any link/button.

You can use a regex to pull the number from the end of the id to find a match on the associated form as below:

`$('a[id^="add-renew-link"]').click(function() {
    var idx = $(this).attr("id").match(/\d+$/)[0];  // Pull index number from id
    $("#add-renew-form" + idx).show();
});`

This jsbin has a full working example.

http://jsbin.com/xicuwi/1/edit

Answer (score 1):

You can't have multiple DOM elements with the same ID. What you can do here is to assign classes for the elements:

```
<div class="add-renew-link"></div>  <div class="add-renew-form"></div>
```

And then use `.each`

```
$('.add-renew-link').each( function(x){

    $(this).click(function(){
       $(".add-renew-form:eq("+x+")").show();
    });

});
```

[You can check out the JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/PExJ3/1/).

Answer (score 0):

Try, using the `.each()` method:

```
$('[id^="add-renew-link"]').each(function(i){
  var ths = $(this);
  (function(i){
    ths.click(function(){
      $('#add-renew-form'+i).show();
    }
  })(i);
});
```

Comment: This function needs I as an argument, how can I pass it?

Comment: `i` is increment in the `.each()` loop. What function?